# Swig - c++ vector of a struct and how to interface them

Tags: python, c++, swig

I am writing a c++ library and I would love to be able to call it in python.
I would love to use swig I am successfully able to create and compile the python module, but I struggle a bit on understanding how to interface python and c++.

```
struct twod {
        double x; ///< x value
        double y; ///< y value
    };

    double distance_calculation(std::vector <twod>  A, std::vector <twod> B);
```

This is a snap of my header file. Following my .i file:

```
%module hausdorff
%{
#include "Hausdorff.h"
using namespace hausdorff;
%}


%include "std_vector.i"
%include "Hausdorff.h"
namespace std {
    %template(vector2d) vector<twod>;
}
```

In python I am able to create the object:

```
In [13]: vector = hausdorff.vector2d

In [14]: vector = ([1,2], [3,4])

In [15]: result = hausdorff.distance_calculation(vector, vector)
```

And I get as error:

```
TypeError: in method 'distance_calculation', argument 1 of type 'std::vector< hausdorff::twod,std::allocator< hausdorff::twod > >'
```

How can I pass the right object to the function?

Answer (score 0):

It's a little more complicated than that, at least without more work:

```
>>> import hausdorff
>>> v = hausdorff.vector2d()
>>> a = hausdorff.twod()
>>> a.x = 1.2
>>> a.y = 2.3
>>> v.push_back(a)
>>> a.x = 3.4
>>> a.y = 4.5
>>> v.push_back(a)
>>> test.distance_calculation(v,v)
```

If you provide constructors for your structure, you can simplify:

```
>>> test.distance_calculation([test.twod(1.2,3.4),test.twod(1.2,3.4)],
                              [test.twod(4.5,6.7),test.twod(1.2,3.4)])
```

If you provide typemap conversions, which I leave as a exercise (or another SO question :^) this can be done:

```
>>> test.distance_calculation([(1.1,2.2),(3.3,4.4)],[(5.5,6.6),(7.7,8.8)])
```